# What is the equivalent of DBRef in spring-data-elasticsearch

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

What is the equivalent of DBRef in spring-data-elasticsearch, if you want to bind to a different index like an FK association or should it be only based on document id (i.e. the identifier for the document)

```
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/DBRef.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept like this in Elasticsearch to reference documents in other indices.

You can store the id of a document in index1 in a property of a document that is stored in index2. But it is your responsibility when reading from index2 to also retrieve the corresponding data from index1. There is no automatic resolution of such references and there are no integrity checks.